# SOAP via jax-ws: entity classes missing in schema

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

So, I have a soap server-side project. Annotations - `@WebService` over interface and implementation, `@WebMethod` over interface' methods, `@XmlRootElement` over entity-classes that are in return and arguments in web-methods, and `@XmlElement` over their fields(over getters actually). Tried also partially and fully swap `@XmlRootElement` with `@XmlType`, and `@XmlElement` with `@XmlAttribute`.

Project is launched via publisher class or via Tomcat(WSServletContextListener), everything's working after weeks of trial and error. In WSDL schema, for instance:

```
<xsd:element name="Sell_i">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="session" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="terminal" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="info" nillable="true" type="tns:TransactionSellInfo"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Represents the `Sell_i` method. `TransactionSellInfo` is an input argument here, and tns points to this namespace aka this wsdl. So, it should be described here. It of course has all the annonations. But, it's just missing, as well as every other class. What's the solution?

Worth noting: schema type is `RPC`(tho changing to `Document` doesn't cause classes to appear in wsdl). Also, on the same machine wsimport from wsdl creates classes for those missing entities, which is very wierd(didn't test wsimport on other machines tho). But soapUI won't work with that wsdl and rightfully says that it's malformed.

Maybe it's something quite basic that I'm missing, but google gives nothing useful on all my tries. Any help is appreciated!